# Generacion de format toString

Tags: java, string

Estoy haciendo un método que genere el format para el toString, en matrices, el problema que me surge es que me manda el error:

> MissingFormatArgumentException

este es el código que tengo:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[][] matrixString ={{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int[][] matrixString1 ={{3, 1, 2}, {6, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 1}};
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixString.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixString[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print("[" + print(matrixString) + "]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static String[][] print(int[][] matrix){
    String[][] formatString;
    formatString = new String [matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
    String formatLine = toString(matrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            formatString[i][j] = String.format(formatLine, matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return formatString;
}
public static String toString(int[][] matrix){
    String formatLine = "";
    int number = 0;
    int cant = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            cant++;
            number = matrix[i][j];
            String number1 = String.valueOf(number);
            System.out.println(number1);
            formatLine += ("%" + cant + "$-" + (number1.length() + 1) + "s ");
            System.out.println(formatLine);
        }
        cant = 0;
        formatLine += "\n";
    }
    return formatLine;
}
```

el error, lo manda en esta linea:

> formatLine += ("%" + cant + "$-" + (number1.length() + 1) + "s ");

y en salida me manda este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%-2$2s'
>       at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
>       at pruebas.prueba.toString1(prueba.java:20)
>       at pruebas.prueba.main(prueba.java:9)

quiero que me salga el formato de cada linea de la matriz asi:

> %1$-2s %2$-2s %3$-2s 
>   %1$-2s %2$-2s %3$-2s 
>   %1$-2s %2$-2s %3$-2s

y dependiendo la longitud del numero cambie

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código entero o señalar la línea en la que te da el error?

Comment: ¿Crees que puedas agregar una matriz de ejemplo y la salida deseada ya con formato?

Comment: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hola Yeferson. Con tu última edición, tu pregunta es mucho mas clara, y se puede reproducir tu error. Lo único que falta, pero muy importante, es lo que te pidió @Paul Vargas: *la salida deseada ya con formato*.

Comment: No se entiende que salida deseas, danos un ejemplo

Comment: Por favor, tomate la molestia de cuidar que el codigo que copias corresponde exactamente al que ejecutaste cuando tuviste la exception! Ese seguramente no es. (Para empezar, `toString1` no existe).

Answer (score 0):

Probá cambiando la linea

```
formatLine += ("%" + cant + "$-" + (number1.length() + 1) + "s ");
```

por

```
formatLine += ("%%" + cant + "$-" + (number1.length() + 1) + "s ");
```